# How to covnert Hex to Dec int32 and vice versa in PHP?

Tags: php

Can someone suggest a best way to convert hex to dec and vice versa in PHP (equivalent to the PowerShell commands below)?

```
$hex = "0x80070020"
$hex2dec = [Convert]::ToInt32($hex,16) 
write-host $hex2dec #output: -2147024864

$dec = "-2147024864"
$dec2hex = "0x{0:X}" -f [Int]$hex 
write-host $dec2hex #output: 0x80070020
```

I tried following approach in PHP.

```
echo $val = hexdec(80070020) //returns Int64, need Int32.
echo $val = dechex(-2147024864) //returns ffffffff80070020, can use string replacement but wondering if there is any other best way.
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What's the goal? Save it as 32bit int or print the result? The first can be done with pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the hex > dec you could use:

```
$hex = '80070020';
$dec = unpack('l', pack('l', hexdec($hex)))[1];
```

This will put it into the 32bit binary representation and read it as signed 32bit int.

Comment: kuh-chan, this worked perfectly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply truncate it to 32-bits:

```
$x = hexdec(1234) & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

If you need it to be signed you can simply subtract `pow(2, 31)` from it:

```
$x -= 0x80000000
```